# Как в плагине mmenu урезать длину меню?

Tags: html, css

порылся в настройках, но так и не нашел объекта, задав которому ширину можно укоротить меню.

Как надо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Light', arial;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 310px;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*section main*/


.info {

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 120px;
  left: 80px;
  z-index: 70;
  padding: 20px;

}

.info-text {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.info-text h2 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;

}
.info-text p {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
.info-button {
  background-color: #b36060;
  font-family: Lora;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.info-button:hover {
    outline: 2px solid white !important;
    
}

.arrow {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
/*sidebar*/
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 80;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 310px;
  background: #5b5858 url(../img/menu_bg.jpg) center repeat;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.logo {
  width: 245px;
  height: 76px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(197, 120, 64, 0.65);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.logo h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}
.logo span {
  position: absolute; 
  transform: translate(-15%, 80%);
  background: url(../img/menu_bg.jpg);
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 14.2px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.desc p {
  text-align: justify;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  width: 245px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #aaa9a9;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.menu-main {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.menu-main ul li:nth-child(2):before {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: '1';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: url(../img/rectangle.svg) center no-repeat;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.menu-main ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.menu-main ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff7200;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.menu-main li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #686464;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.menu-sub ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bdbdbd;
}
.menu-sub ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.contact a.phone {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fefefe;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.contact a.request {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #c57c40;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #c57c40;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.contact a.request:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*Slider*/


.img {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
} 

.owl-nav {
  display: none;
}

.owl-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}

.owl-dot {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #ffff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.owl-dot.active {
  transform: scale(1.8);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/*Popup*/
.popup{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 100;
}

.popup-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 980px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
   
}

.popup-form {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.popup-img img  {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 50px;
}


.form-input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}


.popup-form h3 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.popup-form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 5px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}
 

.popup-form  p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup-form input:focus, .popup-form textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #b75d5d;
}

.popup-form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}


.popup h3 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.095em;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

.popup sup {
  color: #b25252;
   font-size: 14px;
}

.popup p {

  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #716d6d;
}

.popup-form button.send {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  background-color: #db7d3a;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Lora;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}


.popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #796454;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Mobile header*/

.header {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  background: #5b5858 url(../img/menu_bg.jpg) center repeat;
  
}

.mobmenu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}




.mobnav i {
  color: #fff;
  
}

.fas.fa-bars {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
}

.open .fas.fa-bars {
  display: none !important;
}

.fas.fa-times {
  display: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
}

.open .fas.fa-times {
  display: inline-block !important;
}



.hamburger-inner, .hamburger-inner:after, .hamburger-inner:before {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 2.5px !important;
}

.hamburger-wrapper {
  border-right: 1px solid #686464;
}

.hamburger {
  padding: 10px !important;

}

.hamburger-box {
  width: 32px !important;
}
  

  /*Mmenu styles*/
.mm-navbar {
  background-color: #dfddd8 !important;
  padding: 15px;
}

.mm-navbar span {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

.mm-panel {
  background-color: #eceae6 !important;
}





.mm-listitem {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 43px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  color: #6a5346 !important;

}




@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }

  .content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 55px;
  }

  .header h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  .header h2.close {
    display: none;
  }


  .icons a {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
    
  
  .icons a.trolley {
    position: relative;
  }

  .notification {
    position: absolute;
    top: -33px;
    right: 0;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #db7d3a;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .icons img {
    height: 17px;
    padding:  20px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .mobnav {
    display: inline-block;
  }

.mobnav, .icons img {
    border-right: 1px solid #686464;
  }
    

  .icons img.loupe {
    border-left: 1px solid #686464;
  }

  .icons img.phone {
    border-right: none;
  }

  .icons img:nth-child(5){
    content: '0';
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }

  .popup-wrapper {
    margin: 0 10%;
  }
  
}




@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .popup-img {
        display:none;
    }
}



@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
    .popup-form {
        padding: 60px 20px;
    }

    .popup-close {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/clear.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adaptive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mmenu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hamburgers.min.css">
    <link href="https://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=open-sans-light" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=noto-sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/7dca09e227fdfe16908cebb4244589e4?family=Georgia" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/mmenu.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8e0bceeac7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Сияние - Декор центр</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="my-page">
            <div class="popup">

                <div class="popup-wrapper">
                    
                    <div class="popup-img">

                        <img src="img/popup_img.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="popup-form">
                        <button class="popup-close">&times;</button>
                        <h3>обратная связь</h3>
                        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form" onsubmit="send(event, 'mail.php')">
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <p>E-mail <sup>*</sup></p>
                            <input type="email" name="user_email" required>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <p>Телефон <sup>*</sup></p>
                                <input type="tel" name="user_phone" required>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <p>Сообщение</p>
                                <textarea name="user_comment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            
                             <button class="send" type="submit">Отправить</button>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    
                        <div class="top-content">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <h1>сияние</h1>
                                    <span>декор центр</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    <p>Интернет-магазин отделочных материалов и дизайна</p>
                                </div>
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu">

                            <div class="menu-main">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">каталог товаров</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">новости и акции</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">наши услуги</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">портфолио</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">блог</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">контакты</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="menu-sub">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Отзывы о нас</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Дизайнеры</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="contact">
                            <a href="tel:+78005118909" class="phone">+7 (4822) 648-080</a>
                            <a href="#" class="request">Заказать звонок</a>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="header">
                    <div class="mobmenu">
                        <!-- <a class="hamburger-wrapper" href="#mmenu">
                            <div class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze">
                              <div class="hamburger-box">
                                <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </a> -->
                        <div class="mobnav">
                            <a href="#mmenu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
                            <a href="#mmenu"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#"><h2>сияние</h2></a>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href="#"><img class="loupe" src="img/icons/loupe.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/scale.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/heart.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/user.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a class="trolley" href="#"><div class="notification">0</div><img src="img/icons/trolley.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#"><img class="phone" src="img/icons/phone.svg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                    <div class="gallery">
                        <div class="owl-carousel">
                            
                            <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-1.jpg);" class="div"></div>
                            <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-2.jpg);" class="div"></div>
                            <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-3.jpg);" class="div"></div>
                            <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-4.jpg);" class="div"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="info-text">
                            <h2>Декоративные покрытия</h2>
                            <p>от лучших производителей</p>
                        </div>
                        <button class="info-button">Подробнее <span class="
                        arrow">&rarr;</span> </button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
            
    <nav id="mmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">каталог товаров</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">новости и акции</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">наши услуги</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">портфолио</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">блог</a></li>
            <li><a href="">контакты</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Отзывы о нас</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Дизайнеры</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>          
</body>

    
<script>
// Отправка данных на сервер
function send(event, php){
console.log("Отправка запроса");
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', php, true);
req.onload = function() {
    if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
    json = JSON.parse(this.response); 
        console.log(json);
        
        // ЗДЕСЬ УКАЗЫВАЕМ ДЕЙСТВИЯ В СЛУЧАЕ УСПЕХА ИЛИ НЕУДАЧИ
        if (json.result == "success") {
            // Если сообщение отправлено
            alert("Сообщение отправлено");
        } else {
            // Если произошла ошибка
            alert("Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено");
        }
    // Если не удалось связаться с php файлом
    } else {alert("Ошибка сервера. Номер: "+req.status);}}; 

// Если не удалось отправить запрос. Стоит блок на хостинге
req.onerror = function() {alert("Ошибка отправки запроса");};
req.send(new FormData(event.target));
}
</script>
 
            
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас для класса `sidebar` указана ширина в 310 пикселов. Оттуда она и тянется. Отключите.